# How to set a default character set for a table in MySQL and MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am forward engineering a MySQL database from an EER diagram in MySQL workbench, and am being shown the following error on the execution of the statement below:

```
ERROR: Error 1115: Unknown character set: 'DEFAULT'
```

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `recipes_database_2`.`cleaned_string` (
          `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `string` VARCHAR(511) CHARACTER SET 'DEFAULT' NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
          UNIQUE INDEX `string_UNIQUE` (`string` ASC) VISIBLE)
        ENGINE = InnoDB
        AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
        DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = DEFAULT
```

What can I change to fix this? I want the character set to be the one I set as the default for the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't specify the `CHARACTER SET` at all, then the

> database character set and collation are used

as one can read from the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-table.html).